# How to add md5 hash to js and css files with grunt?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I want to append the md5 to all `js` and `css` files when running `grunt` as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?md5hash" />
<script src="script.js?md5hash"></script>
```

Is that possible? I could only find grunt plugins that acutally rename the script file itself and include the hash. But I want to keep the filename always the same, just change the reference md5 name in the `index.html`.

Comment: What for do you need that? Usually `?v=md5hash` is added by server for managing cache. Anyway if you want to add md5 id would be better to add it like this `script-md5hash.js` so file extension would be js

Answer (score 0):

Check out [grun-cache-bust](https://github.com/hollandben/grunt-cache-bust). It does just that.

Disclarimer: I've only used gulp-cache-bust but I suppose it's the same thing. Not only does it compute hash sums for your scripts, it also searches your html files and updates any references.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The name of the package is linked. A bit quick on the downvote button there?

Comment: I think what you need to do is show some actual code or else this is just a comment and not an actual answer. Don't just link to a library - give an example here how the OP can accomplish his goals using that library.